# AWS Glue | API call | Python Shell | Connection | Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: python, aws-glue

We are trying to call An API using Python Shell in AWS glue. We are making an HTTPS call using python 3.6 using "requests" library. The issue is pertaining to AWS glue.

The Job config is
Python Shell
Python 3 ( Glue Version 1.0 )

### This is the error that we get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f862b3b4160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api-v2/client/orders/?auth_token=#####&start_date=01-04-2021&end_date=02-04-2021&status_filter=all&page_number=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f862b3b4160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 123, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(temp_file_path, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-fhh0x612/test.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api-v2/client/orders/?auth_token=#####0&start_date=01-04-2021&end_date=02-04-2021&status_filter=all&page_number=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f862b3b4160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-fhh0x612/test.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api-v2/client/orders/?auth_token=####&start_date=01-04-2021&end_date=02-04-2021&status_filter=all&page_number=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f862b3b4160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

Is there an issue with the security group that AWS Glue refers to or some issue with the API call. We are not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there more than one connection from glue? like calling S3 , redshift...etc. if more than one then u may have to add other connections in connection properties. Edit job -> add connection.